# WooCommerce template outdated notice doesn't disappear on "System Status" page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My site uses a custom theme where **I am overriding** some WooCommerce templates. After receiving outdated notices, I updated those templates with their respective recommended versions by downloading the latest WooCommerce plugin from WordPress repository.

Ideally, those outdated notices should disappear by now, but they are still displaying on `WooCommerce > System Status` page.

I am taking reference of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dy7yBzxm72E).

The site is not using any caching plugin. I cleared browser cache and cookies, closed and reopened the browser, stopped and restarted local web server (I am using [lando](https://pantheon.jp/docs/guides/lando-wordpress) to set up the site in my local environment) cookies and everything else but with no luck! They are still showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try clear Woocommerce templates cache.

Go to the WP Dashboard -> Woocommerce -> Status -> Tools -> "Clear the template cache".